# Editing text messages with keyboards in C# Telegram Bots

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I sent a message with inline keyboard (with `SendTextMessageAsync` and `InlineKeyboardMarkup`).
When I tried to edit at the first time - `EditMessageTextAsync` (with `InlineKeyboardMarkup`) method working fine, but when I trying to modify this message at the second time I got

> Bad Request: message is not modified.

The code:

```
response = string.Format("...");
rkm = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
//...
rkm.InlineKeyboard = new[]
{
    new[] { InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("...", "/filters") }
};
await client.EditMessageTextAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, update.CallbackQuery.Message.MessageId, response, replyMarkup: rkm);
```

The exception:

> Bad Request: message is not modified
>      at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.d__109`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>      at AutoSearch.Notifications.Sources.Telegram.TelegramBot.d__7.MoveNext()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the keyboard **Only** use `EditMessageReplyMarkupAsync`

Otherwise if you want to edit the message content **and** the keyboard use `EditMessageTextAsync`

Exception Example:

```cs
// Defining Message data
string text = "<b>Hello World</b>";
int myChatId = 142536987; // Some chat
InlineKeyboardButton btn = InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("DoSomething");

// Sending message
Message msg = await SendTextMessageAsync(myChatId, text, ParseMode.Html, true, false, 0, btn);



// New keyboard for message
InlineKeyboardButton newBtn = InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Return");

// DON'T DO THAT:
// EXCEPTION!
//>>> MESSAGE IS NOT MODIFIDE!
// You must change the text...
msg = await EditTextMessageAsync(msg.Chat, msg.MessageId, text, true, newBtn);


// True way to edit the keyboard without text
msg = await EditMessageReplyMarkup(msg.Chat, msg.MessageId, newBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this sort of error, it just “not modified” because of new text in same with old one.

If you want to solve this error, just add time stamp like *“Last Modified: 6:57 PM”*.

Comment: Yes, the message was the same, but replyMarkup changed. I want to change it to create a new `menu`. I tried to change it with `EditMessageReplyMarkupAsync` but the result is the same.